# Стеганография. Сокрытие информации в *.bmp

Tags: bmp, стеганография

Задача - провести исследование вносимых изменений в изображении при стеганографии.

Алгоритм выполнения программы:

1. Картинка представляется в бинарном виде.
2. Каждый пиксель занимает 3 байта.
3. Мы накладываем маску, в которой n младших битов, которые мы собираемся заменять, заполнены нулями. Таким образом отбрасываем эти младшие биты.
4. Берем очередной кусочек шифруемого текста, сдвигаем побитово на так, что бы в младших разрядах оказалась новая порция шифруемых битов.
5. После этого накладываем фильтрующую маску и складываем с байтами, полученными на шаге 3.

Я реализовал получение байт массивов из изображения и текстового сообщения. Теперь необходимо внести изменения в изображения, так как глубина цвета 24 бита один пиксель будет представлять из себя 00110010 для R, 00010110 для G, 00000011 для B, моя задача внести изменения в младшие биты, руководствуясь значениями numericUpDown для R, G и B. Допустим R = 2, G = 0, B = 0, значит мне нужно заменить первые два нуля в байте 00110010 на биты из текстового сообщения и так для всего изображения, ну и вывести его для наглядности. Как это сделать?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Steganography
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp) | *.bmp";
            openDialog.InitialDirectory = @"e:\OneDrive\Projects\CSharpProjects\Steganography\Steganography\Steganography\bin\Debug";
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tB_FileInfo.Clear();
                lFilePath.Text = openDialog.FileName;
                tB_FileInfo.Text += "File path : " +lFilePath.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                pB_DecyptImage.ImageLocation = lFilePath.Text;
                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(lFilePath.Text);
                tB_FileInfo.Text += "PhysicalDimension : " + image.PhysicalDimension + Environment.NewLine;
                tB_FileInfo.Text += "PixelFormat : " + image.PixelFormat + Environment.NewLine;
                tB_FileInfo.Text += "VerticalResolution : " + image.VerticalResolution + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        private void steganographyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Стеганография служит для скрытия секретных сообщений в других сообщениях, причем так, что скрывается даже само существование секрета. Как правило, отправитель пишет какое-нибудь невинное сообщение, а затем скрывает секретное сообщение на этом же листе бумаги. Из истории к нам пришли такие хитроумные средства, как использование невидимых чернил, тончайшие булавочные наколки возле отдельных символов, малозаметные отличия букв, написаных от руки, пометки карандашом машинописных символов, решетки, накрывающие большую часть сообщения, кроме нескольких символов и т.д.Недавно люди начали скрывать секретные сообщения в графических изображениях.При этом младший бит каждого байта изображения заменяется битом сообщения.Само графическое изображение меняется совершенно незначительно, поскольку большинство графических стандартов определяют намного большее число цветовых градаций, чем способен различить человеческий глаз.На принимающей стороне сообщение извлекается.Так, в полутоновом(черно - белом) рисунке размером 1024Г—1024 пикселей можно скрыть сообщение размером 64 Кбайт, причем для этого годятся многие общедоступные приложения. Для маскировки сообщений также можно использовать имитационные функции Питера Уэйнера(Peter Wayner).Эти функции изменяют сообщение так, что его статические параметры прибретают сходство с каким - либо иным текстом: разделом сообщений Нью - Йорк Таймс, драмой Шекспира или телеконференцией в Интернете.Этот тип стеганографии не обманет человека, но может обмануть мощный компьютер, сканирующий Интернет в поисках нужной информации. Прикладная криптография Брюс Шнайер");
        }

        public void bEncode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // создаем битмап изображения
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(lFilePath.Text);

            // получаем эксклюзивный доступ к внутренним данным битмапа
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                bmp.PixelFormat);

            // получаем адрес первого пикселя в данных битмапа
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // объявляем массив для значений RGB
            int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

            // копируем все значения RGB в массив
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

            string rgbString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rgbValues);

            // байт массив сообщения
            String toEncode = tB_Message.Text;
            byte[] toEncB = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
            int lenTE = toEncB.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот программы]

[Исходник](http://rghost.ru/7mtzCpqKL)